Publishing certain modules with Jitpack
I'm following Clean Architecture in order to publish some libraries.
Example: SimpleCalculator and AdvancedCalculator libraries.
They both share the same domain logic, so they can share the domain module, thus, it is included as an implementation in their build.gralde files. The project also include other modules such as data, di, core... but those are just modules needed to build SimpleCalculator and AdvancedCalculator. 
Important mention is for example, data is an Android Module but, for example,  domain is just a pure JVM library. 
I'm adding the id("maven-publish") to the libraries as I want to publish only those 2 modules, SimpleCalculator and AdvancedCalculator, which are the libraries. I'm not interested in publishing domain, data, etc... too, even though I don't really mind if they are fetched, anyways shouldn't be needed as those modules are just used to build right the SimpleCalculator and AdvancedCalculator aars, am I right?
What is happening now is Jitpack is building the libraries correctly, but when I fetch one of the libraries, for example: 
com.macro.calculators:advanced-calculator:0.0.1
Attempts to also fetch all the modules that are on the project and Jitpack answers just for those modules with a 401, something very strange. The library is public on Jitpack. It's like fetches just the pom but the rest fails.

What is going on? How could I achieve such a thing?
I'm using Kotlin DSL for Gradle and a build logic module in order to manage all the plugins of the gradle.files's of the different modules of the project.
Any help is welcome, let me know if you need more details.

I solved it by publishing the rest of modules. Same as Jitpack support answered to my opened issue.
Hope this helps somebody in the future.
https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/6544
